# OpenCv Java : Matlab code to Java equivalency

Tags: java, android, matlab, opencv

i am trying to convert MATLAB code in java for that i am using OpenCv for android.

i want to implement this function of MATLAB in java im2double(Image). is their any ready-made function in opencv or java to do so in android. or we have to implement our own function kindly help if anyone has implemented this already. i have searched Google but didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Do you know what im2double does?

Comment: converts image to image of class double

Comment: Ok, do you know what types of images can `cv::Mat` hold?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use the equivalent to C++ `Mat::convertTo()` function, which is implemented in Java as

```
public void assignTo(Mat m, int type)
```

where `m` is the destination matrix and `type` is the data type/depth you want to convert your data to (in this case I think you want to use `CV_64FCX`, where `'X'` is the number of channels).

Hope that it helps!

Answer (score 1):

[http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#convertTo(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int)](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#convertTo%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int%29)

```
Mat someformat;    // src    
Mat doubleformat;  // dst

someformat.convertTo( doubleformat, CvType.CV_64F );
```

note, that this just changes the type/depth of the single elements, not the number of channels